# Remove a single commit from history

Tags: git

In my history, I have 1 commit that seems to be duplicated for some reason (checked the diff and are exactly equal).

```
$ git log pretty=oneline
...
...
d21971dd55e4b4f62421b6531b3fd1e65102974d Add Source Sans Pro required weights
...
...
8aaba297017086094b60087b5601ccc01d50be54 Add Source Sans Pro required weights
...
...
```

This changes are in a branch that wasn't pushed yet. How can I get rid of one of those duplicated commits?

**EDIT:** The dots between the commit logs doesn't means that there are exactly two commits between them. There are more than 10 in some cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get rid of commit `d21971` you could do

```
git rebase -i d21971^
```

It will open your text editor with the list of commit up to the parent of commit `d21971`. Just delete the line with commit `d21971`, save and quit. It will delete it.

To make sure you won't lose any commit even if you make an error, you could tag your current branch first. For example:

```
git tag safetyTag
git rebase -i d21971^
#Decide that you don't like what you just did
git checkout safetyTag
git branch -f master
```

Comment: But note that this is rewriting history, anybody who cloned your repository from before will be left hanging to dry. Also note that the missing commit may mean a cascade of conflicts in the following commits.